# Bottom Navigation View look horrible

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to implement a bottom navigation view, it is shown but look terrible, I can't understand why. I want it to show three item.

[here's what is shown in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRfGG.png)

Here's the activity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

NavController navController;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


}
}
```

The layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0-alpha06"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0-alpha06"
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

I did't do any tipe of change of app theme

edit:

menu file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
   android:id="@+id/home"
   android:title="Home"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/social"
    android:title="Socia"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/search_user"
    android:title="Search User" />

</menu>
```

Comment: ^ agree with @jsotola, also based on menu file there is no `android:icon` so this kind of view is expected.

Comment: @jsotola I want it to show 3 item but it shows only one and why is black? I didn't set any background, it should be white isn't it?